# Open datepicker with certain date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I'm having an input filled with a date in the past. All i want to do is open the datepicker of that input on current date.

Example: Input is filled with 10 nov 2011, onclick should open datepicker starting at 5 feb 2013

Html:

`<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-today="5-2-2013" value="10-11-2011" />`

Javascript:

```
var currentDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', $('#datepicker').data('today'));
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        defaultDate: currentDate,
        dateformat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

With this codesample the datepicker still opens at november 2011

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? Also, are you seeing the issue cross-browser? It seems to behave according to your desires when I copied your code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5xWh/) using Chrome and the latest versions of the scripts.

Comment: Hey your right! Ill try to figure out the differences of the example and my code

Comment: Thx to you comment i've found out that jquery.ui-datepicker-nl.js is causing the conflict. Ill post an update if i find the solution for current issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

> Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format (e.g., "01/26/2009"), a number of days from today (e.g., +7) or a string of values and periods ("y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, "d" for days, e.g., "+1m +7d"), or null to clear the selected date.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", currentDate );
```

Comment: Unfortunately setDate will change the value of the input too. All i want is the original value of the input and open the datepicker on today's date